# Tengo un problema con la foto de perfil de mi página web, es que queda debajo del banner. La foto se veia bien hasta que inserte el link de bootsrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, web, imagen

Estoy diseñando mi primera página web y tengo un problema que no puedo solucionar. Mi imagen de perfil queda por debajo de mi banner, es decir, el banner tapa a la imagen de perfil.
El problema surge cuando introduzco el link de bootstrap en el código, si no uso bootstrap la imagen se ve bien.
Ya intenté con otros archivos de bootstrap, de manera local como también CDN, y el problema persiste, intenté cambiar el orden del banner y la imagen de perfil en el código CSS pero queda igual.
Este es mi código HTML y CSS.

```html
<body>
  <div class="card mat-card" id="first-card">
    <div id="profile-background"> <img src="code-banner.jpg"></div>
    <div id="info" style="padding: 16px">
      <div id="info-img">
        <img class="profile-image" src="profile img ramiro.jpg">
      </div>
```

```css
.mat-card {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.8px;
    border-radius:32px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-color: #0a66c2;  
}
.mat-card#first-card {
    padding: 0;
}
div#profile-background {
    display: flex;
    z-index: 1;
}
div#profile-background img {
    width: 100% ;
    border-radius:  32px 32px 0 0;
}
.profile-image {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 152px;
    height: 152px;
    margin-top: -110px;
}
```

[image: Sin utilizar bootstrap]

[image: Utilizando bootstrap]

Comment: Agrega todo el CSS de la `card` y del `profile-background`

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz Ya agregue el código que me faltaba

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera:

```
#profile-background {
    display: flex;
    /*z-index: 1;*/ /*sin z-index */
}

#info {
    z-index: 1; /* 1 ó más */
    position: relative
}

.profile-image {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 152px;
    height: 152px;
    margin-top: -110px;
    z-index: 1 /* opcional */
}
```

Cuando un objeto está debajo de otro, éste debe tener un `z-index` mayor del que lo está cubriendo

Comment: Solucionado. Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: @RamiroFV no olvides marcar ✓ para no dejar pendiente tu pregunta